# Je préférerais / préférerai ce lundi soir

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

Quelqu'un m'a écrit :

> Avez-vous une préférence entre lundi et mardi soir ?

Je lui ai répondu :

> Je **préférerais** ce lundi soir, mais sinon les deux journées me vont
> pour la discussion.

Le conditionnel est correct ici, cf. ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17817/je-pr%C3%A9f%C3%A9rerais-is-the-more-polite-way-of-saying-je-pr%C3%A9f%C3%A8re). Mais est-ce qu'il y a ici une condition sous-entendue ou il s'agit d'un conditionnel de politesse ?

Comment: C'est un [conditionnel de politesse](http://flemotion.com/conditionnel-politesse-francais-fle-delf.html).

Comment: Merci pour vos réponses.

Answer (score 1):

Comme indiqué en commentaire, il s'agit d'un [conditionnel de politesse](http://flemotion.com/conditionnel-politesse-francais-fle-delf.html) [²](http://www.french-learning.eu/grammar-6-10/conditionnel-politesse/).

Ça n'empêche pas une condition implicite, sous-entendue d'être imaginée pour compléter la phrase :

> **Si** je peux me permettre, je préfèrerais [...]
> **Si** ça ne vous embête pas, je préfèrerais [...]
> **Si** j'osais exprimer mon choix, je préfèrerais [...]
> etc.

Comment: Merci, mais je pense qu'il est possiblier d'y rattacher une condition : par exemple, _Si je me permettais de m'exprimer_, _si je devais parler_.

Comment: Si vous voulez rajouter une informations, c'est possible notamment parce que c'est un wiki et non une réponse simple.

Comment: J'aimerais quand même que des francophones le confirment, le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi remplacer la liste au lieu d'ajouter à la suite ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Indiquer la conjugaison complète du verbe préférer au conditionnel me semble inutile car Oreste indique bien qu'il s'agit d'un conditionnel dans sa question.

Comment: Ah oui, bien vu